# Export values to specific cell in an excel file (using PDI)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have in table input result as below:

[image]

I would like pass this result to excel file in specific row.
For example number_record I want to write to column J5, amount_ma to column K2 and so on. Can something like this be done in pentaho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepare a solution for you [**HERE**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XghKmN-d6uAh4gdZpUEmC67kq5Y-N-WU?usp=sharing). Using this solution, you can specifically tell which field you want to insert in which position in Excel. Like in my solution i told to insert field [NUMBER_RECORD to **C5**, AMOUNT_MA to **D7**,AMOUNT_WD to **B5**] Please run transformation "getData.ktr".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a new sheet to this Excel file, and output a line with the result to the new sheet. And on the old sheet in the cells you need, add formulas with a link to the first row in the new sheet